# how to do push notification to i-pad on windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I have a MVC Web API Project & I need to send push notification to iPad. I have used .cer and .p12 files for this & it is working fine. Now I need to publish it to an azure server but I'm a newbie to azure and don't know where to store and how to access the certificate.

I have tried to upload certificate to the cloud service, but am not able to access it.

I am using the following code:

```
string strDeviceToken = "abcd";
string strPushMessage = "hello";
var payload1 = new NotificationPayload(strDeviceToken, strPushMessage, 1, "default");
payload1.AddCustom("RegionID", "IDQ10150");
var p = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload1 };
var push = new PushNotification(true, certificatePath, "password");
string strfilename = push.P12File;
var message1 = push.SendToApple(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i am using this code and its work
 for http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pandeypradip/apple-push-notification-using-Asp-Net/
Attech Dll above link

- string strDeviceToken ="xyz"
- string strPushMessage="test"
- payload1.AddCustom("RegionID", "IDQ10150");
- var p = new List { payload1 };
- string certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/certificates/xyz.p12");
- var push = new PushNotification(true, certificatePath, "password");
- string strfilename = push.P12File;
- var message1 = push.SendToApple(p);